# Live Agent javascript api not working with omni channel routing

Tags: javascript, liveagent, omnichannel

We have a LiveAgent integration and were using the event function 'sforce.console.chat.onChatStarted' to get details about the chat that agent had accepted and 'sforce.console.chat.onNewMessage' function to get new chat messages. But we found that omni-routing with Live agent for some reason doesn't trigger the 'OnchatStarted' function.
From few of the on the forums suggestion we implemented the EventListner  'sforce.console.ConsoleEvent.PRESENCE.WORK_ACCEPTED',good thing is it works and we can use it instead of 'sforce.console.chat.onChatStarted'.But i am not sure how we can find chat details using any of the information returned from 'sforce.console.ConsoleEvent.PRESENCE.WORK_ACCEPTED' or intercept any of the new messages in chat. Any thoughts will be helpfull here.

Comment: have you found any solution for this?